# DefineConstants works with Run command, but not Build command

Tags: .net-core

I am struggling to understand the differences between `dotnet run` and `dotnet build` commands, in regards to constants defined in the `.csproj` file

`example.csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Test'">
      <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);INCLUDE_TESTS</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

`program.cs`

```cs
using System;

namespace define_example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
#if INCLUDE_TESTS
            Console.WriteLine("It worked!");
#endif
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

If I run `dotnet run -c Test`, -> `It worked! Hello World!`

If I run `dotnet build -c Test`, then `dotnet run {buildpath}` -> `Hello World!`

Why does the defined constant go missing when I run the build command?

Comment: I'm not a .net developer but it looks like that constant is supposed to be available for debug builds which is why you don't see it in production build. Such constants are typically used to log debug info and include tests in your builds.

Answer (score 1):

`dotnet build` and `dotnet run` are both commands that act in relation to a csproj file, not a dll or executable.
`dotnet build` will call the `dotnet restore` command and then build the project.
`dotnet run` will call the `dotnet build` command (this is important to note with respect to your issue) and then run the resulting dll or exe.

What you're currently telling dotnet to do by calling `dotnet build -c Test` and `dotnet run` is:

1. clean, restore, build (using the "Test" configuration)
2. clean, restore, build, run (with no configuration specified)

The second clean will cleanup the files produced by the first build and then you will build again as part of the run command, but without the Test configuration specified, causing the observed behaviour.

You could change `dotnet run` to `dotnet run --no-build` to tell it to assume a build has already been completed and to just assume that the files that would have been created are present and correct.

Alternatively, given that your project has an `OutputType` of `Exe`, you could just invoke the executable that is produced by the build command in the regular way as the second step. i.e. using the command `example.exe`.

If your `OutputType` was unspecified, or the default (`Library`) then this would produce a dll rather than an exe, and you could run it using the `dotnet` command: `dotnet example.dll`.

Useful reading on the various commands and also common properties:

- [dotnet command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet)
- [dotnet build command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build)
- [dotnet run command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run)
- [Common MSBuild project properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Just wanted to add one thing: if you are doing `dotnet bulid` and/or `dotnet publish` yourself, you can just run the dll directly to avoid any surprises from `dotnet run`: `dotnet bin/.../example.dll`. Note that this is just `dotnet example.dll`, not `dotnet run example.dll` (leave out the `run`).